# iOS resize view with auto layout enabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, autolayout

### The given problem

I have the following view that includes a Navigation Bar, Search Bar and table view - the left picture is the given view I have and the right one is what I want to achieve - basically just hide the navigation bar and resize everything.

[image: given] [image: wanted]

### The current solution

Currently I've managed to hide and resize everything using a vertical-space constrain from the search box to the superview top property -

- The default constraint constant is 44 (the navigation bar height)
- After clicking the search box I hide the navigation bar and set the constraint constant to be 0
- When I stop searching I restore the navigation bar and set the constraint to 44 again

[image: vertical-constraint]

### What I want

I'm looking for the *easiest* way to hide the navigation bar and resize the search box + table to fill the whole screen.

Is there *any* way to do it and take advantage of the iOS 6 auto-layout system?

My current solution feels unnatural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that's the only constraint you need to change, then you can create an IBOutlet for that one constraint into your view or view controller, then simply modify the constraint based on when you need it to change:

```
if(shouldHide){
  self.nibTitleBarConstraint.constant = 0.f;
}
else{
  self.nibTitleBarConstraint.constant = 44.f;
}
```

If you'd like to animate the change, then simply stick `-layoutIfNeeded` in an animation context:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f
                 animations:^{
                   [view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

This is applicable to any constraint's constant you would like to modify (height, top space, etc.) so long as your other constraints know how to react with a change in that view's constraints.

Comment: As I wrote in the summary that's exactly what I'm doing right now :)
So it seems to be the best way right now.

Comment: You never mentioned an IBOutlet for the constraint, but yes, this appears to be the best way I can think of to do this. Modifying constants is much more algorithmically efficient than removing/adding constraints and having autolayout solve the constraint set again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: I'm not using navigationController, just a plain navigation bar dropped into a view

Comment: Why are you using the navigation bar for?

Comment: As a title bar, it doesn't really matter actually - I could use a custom view there but still want the same behaviour. Hide it and resize the rest of the views accordingly

Comment: Do you know the KISS principle? Because you are saying that you want to hide it, if you want to hide what's the purpose of having it there to begin with? I don't think I am the only person who is puzzled with what you want to achieve.

Comment: I might not have been clear enough in the summary - my question is more general, I wanted to know what's the best way to make a view resize when another view (that got a constraint with him) is removed, I'll update the summary in a few.